# How do I add content before </body> in extended page? (KID templates)

Tags: python, turbogears

I've got master.kid (simplified):

```
<html>
<head py:match="item.tag == 'head'">
  <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body py:match="item.tag == 'body'">
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <div py:replace="item[:]"></div>
  <p id="footer">Copyright Blixt 2010</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And mypage.kid:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want it to be possible to add more content before the `</body>` tag in the resulting HTML, specific to mypage.kid.

Basically the result should be something this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p id="footer">Copyright Blixt 2010</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">alert('Hello World!');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<script>` tag should be specified in mypage.kid. It's okay if I have to modify master.kid to *optionally* support additional content before the `</body>` tag, but what the content is *has* to be specified in mypage.kid.

At first I figured adding an element before the `</body>` tag in master.kid with `py:match="item.tag == 'bodyend'"` would work. The problem is that it uses the position of the element in mypage.kid, and not the position of the element doing `py:match`. So if I put the `<bodyend>` tag before `</body>` in mypage.kid, it is imported before `<p id="footer">`, and if I put it below `</body>` it will stay there.

How do I set up master.kid and mypage.kid to support adding content immediately before the `</body>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I've found is the following:

master.kid:

```
<html>
<head py:match="item.tag == 'head'">
  <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body py:match="item.tag == 'body'">
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <div py:replace="item[:]"></div>
  <p id="footer">Copyright Blixt 2010</p>
  <div py:if="defined('body_end')" py:replace="body_end()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

mypage.kid:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <div py:def="body_end()" py:strip="True">
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('Hello World!');</script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The master.kid page checks for a variable defined as `body_end`, and if there is such a variable, it will call it, replacing the contents of the element before `</body>` (otherwise it will output nothing).

Any page that needs to output content before `</body>` will define the `body_end` function using `py:def="body_end()"`. The `py:strip="True"` is there to remove the wrapping `<div>`.